# React Typescript Component with variable type (from props)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ref

I want to create a component which accepts its type (e.g. 'div', 'span') from props and children and renders them, the component also supports ref forwarding, and className prop.

The problem is I'm getting an error `'className' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes`, and can't figure out what causes it.

I tried changing the types I provide to `forwardRef` from `HTMLElement` to different ones, googled for similar components, but it was of little help.

When i change `HTMLElement` to, for example, `HTMLDivElement`, and change `<Component ...>` to `<div ...>` this error disappears. So the problem is probably wrong type (`HTMLElement`)

Here is the component code:

```
import React, { ReactChildren, ComponentType } from "react"

interface MyComponentProps {
  children: ReactChildren
  component: string | ComponentType
  className: string
}

const MyComponent = React.forwardRef<HTMLElement, MyComponentProps>(
  (props, ref) => {
    const { children, className, component: Component, ...otherProps } = props

    return (
      <Component className={className} ref={ref} {...otherProps}>
        {children}
      </Component>
    )
  },
)

MyComponent.defaultProps = {
  component: "div",
}

export default MyComponent
```

Expected result: no Typescript errors.

Actual result: the following error appears on a line `<Component className={className} ref={ref} {...otherProps}>`

```
TS2322: Type '{ children: ReactChildren | (ReactChildren & string) | (ReactChildren & number) | (ReactChildren & false) | (ReactChildren & true) | (ReactChildren & ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<...> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)>) | (ReactChildren & ReactNodeArray) | (ReactChildren & Re...' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Property 'className' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
```